# Excel 2010 - Database Query Filtered by Spreadsheet

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, business-intelligence

We have a spreadsheet containing a list of 10,000 customer IDs.

We also have a SQL Server 2008R2 database that has a customers table, containing 20,000,000 customers, and includes attributes like customer ID, first name, email etc.

Preferably within Excel, I want to query the DB and get the first name and email for the 10,000 customers in my spreadsheet.

I do not want to bring back all 20,000,000 records from the DB and then filter for the 10,000 customers because that would be too taxing on the DB (to return 20,000,000 rows).

Im trying to find a way of applying the filter predicate within the DB query to do something like this:

```
SELECT first_name, email 
FROM customers
WHERE customer_id IN (
SELECT customer_id FROM [Excel Spreadsheet]
)
```

I can't do `WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IN ( <comma seperated list of customer_ids> )` within the query, because there are 10,000 customer IDs (integers), and there appears to be a limit on the number of characters you can have in a single SQL statement.

I have PowerPivot, but can't find a way to do it without bringing back the 20 mill customers first.

I don't want to use VBA - the solution needs to be doable for a non technical end user.

Are there any tools that can do this?

Comment: It looks old, but here's [a howto for setting up an ODBC connection from Excel to a SQL Server database](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/solutionbase-making-excel-and-sql-server-talk-to-each-other/5165764).  Then, you can query from Excel as you like.

Comment: Thanks, I can connect to the DB from Excel no problem. The problem is constructing the DB query to use the values in an existing spreadsheet as a filter.

Comment: Can you upload the Excel customer IDs to a temporary table in your database and then build a query on the customer table with an inner join on the temp table? You could automate the upload with VBA/ADO - and provide the non-technical user with a button to trigger the upload or overall update...

Comment: That would work, but is far from ideal... Maybe Excel is not the right tool for the job. I found out it's kind of possible to do in MS Access, where you create a linked table to an Excel spreadsheet, and a linked table to the SQL Server DB table, then you can join the two in a query. Although from running a DB trace, it looks like it still pulls the whole DB table to the client then merges it with the spreadsheet on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm new to this (last thing you want to hear) but my current project is similar in that I'm connecting Excel to my DB and using SQL to call out a specific query to load into my excel sheet. There's a link to a forum that's already questioned this. http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/215327-using-column-data-from-excel-to-use-in-a-sql-query-statement  Hopefully this is of relevance to you as the answers they provide don't use VBA at all, and look quite simple.

Comment: I can't do WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IN ( <comma seperated list of customer_ids> ) within the query, because there are 10,000 customer IDs (integers), and there appears to be a limit on the number of characters you can have in a single SQL statement.

Comment: Sorry I did notice you had Integer values, this is why I thought the link would help as they use the cell reference as a text string example ('" & A1 & "') or (Range("B4").Value). Thought that would chop down the character limit as your not using the actual cell ID number. Sorry it didn't help, all the best for finding the solution.